# Log in to Skype for Business for Office 365 using Sky

Tags: skype

I am trying to use Sky, the Skype for Business client for Linux, as recommended on the Skype forums (where Office 365 was specifically mentioned as a use case). I am using it on Fedora 23. However, it is asking for both an email address and a username, which it hints should be of the form `domain\user`. I ignored that advice because I don't know what domain I should use, and tried just the username part of my email address, and my full email address. Neither of them worked. What should I put as the username?

Comment: For everyone who is about to flag this as not good for UNIX.SE, I do think this fits within the scope of the site. ("Using or administering a *nix desktop or server".)

Comment: Do you have an Office 365 account? AFAIK they're associated with a business, and the domain is your business's name. If you have an email address like `Robin.Green@acme.com`, where your Office 365 account is provided by ACME, then typing your email address where you're asked for `domain\user` should work.

Comment: Yes, I do have a business account, and no that didn't work.

Comment: @Gilles That's exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed the company that made Sky, and they said there is a known bug with sign-in for Office 365 users, and they will fix it eventually.

Comment: Does anyone know if the bug was fixed?

Answer (score 5):

To who googled here:

Finally I sorted it out, I mean using skype for business on ubuntu.

Actually it's a Chrome plugin named ARC Welder, it's a kinda Android emulator in Chrome.

Download here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

After installed it, run it, then just drag the apk of skype for business into it's window, and enjoy!

Comment: PS. pidgin-sipe-1.21.1 works as well under ubuntu 16.04.

See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/682301/how-to-update-pidgin-sipe

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

Internal server name: **sipdir.online.lync.com:443**

External server name: **sipdir.online.lync.com:443**